# I can't modify the 'Continue reading...' link of the_excerpt

Tags: excerpt

I just placed this in my `functions.php` (I'm using Wordpress 3.0.4):

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read the Rest...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

But my post is still displaying `… Continue reading`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@janoChen:**

Your theme *(or a plugin)* is overriding your filter. Try increasing the priority like this:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more',11);
```

Or like this:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more',20);
```

And if that doesn't work try:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more',100);
```